# python class attribute reference side effect?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, reference

I'm confused by a bug in my code :

Given the following class with the method `distribute_tags`

```py
class ConsulData:
    def __init__(self, logger, marshalled_data, prom_numbering, prom_count):
        self.logger = logger
        self.current = marshalled_data
        self.to_update= {}
        self.payloads = []
        self.prom_count = prom_count
        self.prom_numbering = prom_numbering

    def distribute_tags(self):
        cpt = 0
        cp_current = copy.deepcopy(self.current)
        for keys, values in cp_current.items():
            num = (cpt % self.prom_count) + self.prom_numbering
            prometheus_tag = "prometheus-{}".format(num)
            if not prometheus_tag in values['Tags']:
                self.to_update[keys] = values
                data = []
                [data.append(v) for v in values['Tags'] if not v.startswith("prometheus")]
                data.append(prometheus_tag)
                self.to_update[keys]['Tags'] = data
            cpt += 1
    {...}
```

without the deepcopy, after the loop execution, `print(self.current == self.to_update)` return `True`.

And `print(id(self.current) == id(self.to_update))` return False.

The use of `deepcopy` fix the bug which is unexpected to me since what's done inside `distribute_tags` is more or less the same as doing :

```py
In [2]: d1 = {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}
In [3]: d2 = {}

In [4]: for k, v in d1.items():
   ...:     d2[k] = v

In [6]: d2['key1'] = 'lol'

In [8]: d1
Out[8]: {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}

In [9]: d2
Out[9]: {'key1': 'lol', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

In which the d1 data is unaffected by a modification to d2 since they are 2 distinct references to a distinct object.

the marshalled_data passed to the **init** function looks like this :

```
payload = {
    'service1': {
        'ID': 'service1',
        'Service': 'service1', 
        'Tags': ['sre-metrics', 'prometheus-2'], 
        'Meta': {
            'env': 'dev', 
            'namespace': 'test', 
            'path': '/path1', 
            'svc': 'svc1', 
            'team': 'testing'},
        'Port': 80, 
        'Address': 'test1.testing.org', 
        'Weights': {'Passing': 1, 'Warning': 1}, 
        'EnableTagOverride': False
    }, 
...
```

Comment: `self.to_update[keys] = values` doesn't make a copy of `values`. So when you do `self.to_update[keys]['Tags'] = data` you're also modifying the original dictionary if you don't use `deepcopy()`

Comment: thanks @Barmar I take it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't make a deep copy,

```
self.to_update[keys] = values
```

assigns a reference to the same `values` dictionary. When you later do

```
self.to_update[keys]['Tags'] = data
```

you're modifying that dictionary, so both values are still equal.